# Connecting Google-Domains to Cloud-run URL

Tags: google-compute-engine, dns-server, google-domains

Does anybody know how to connect my Cloud-Run URL with a Google Domain?  I'd prefer to use Google Domains DNS server.  I ping successfully at at what Cloud Run assigned me in Domain Mappings(also in AppEngine-Settings), and which I entered into my Custom Resource Records in Google Domains.  I have a Network services-Cloud DNS Zone, but don't have any A or AAAA records entered.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had too much information entered into domains.google.com, like A and AAAA records into custom resource records. All I needed was the NS record. Probably A and AAAA are only for static IP's. My domain mappings in cloud run only needed a CNAME record which I entered into my Cloud DNS Zone records and it worked. Also, my allowed hosts had to include my registered domain. Thanks for nothing.